# Can't get JSON string's element

Tags: javascript, json

I'm totally new to javascript and I'm trying to display an array of object which is stored in local storage using javascript and html and display each element of the JSON string in `td` tag of a table

In `studentList.js` file, first of all, I create a `Student` object:

```
function Student(id, name, birthDay, gender, falcuty, point ) {
   this.id = id
   this.name = name
   this.birthDay = birthDay 
   this.gender = gender
   this.falcuty = falcuty
   this.point = point
}

var table = document.getElementById("table-stud")
```

And an array of 'Student' object:

```
var collection = [];
collection.push(new Student("01","A","20/11/1998","M","IT","8.0"),
            new Student("02","B","2/1/1998","F","IT","8.0"),
            new Student("03","C","9/9/1997","F","CK","8.8"))
```

Save student in local storage:

```
function saveStudent(collection) {
    for(var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
        var studentObjectSerialiseData = JSON.stringify(collection[i])
        console.log(studentObjectSerialiseData)
        window.localStorage.setItem("student"+i, studentObjectSerialiseData)
    }
}
```

Display students:

```
function getStudents() {
    console.log(Student.length)
    for(var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {

        var studentObjectSerialiseData = window.localStorage.getItem("student"+i)
        var temp = JSON.parse(studentObjectSerialiseData)
        var tr = document.createElement("tr")
        for(var j = 0; j < Student.length; j++) {    
            var td = document.createElement("td")
            td.innerText = temp[j]
            tr.appendChild(td)     
        }
        table.appendChild(tr)
    }
}

saveStudent(collection);
getStudents();
```

In HTML file, I called studentList.js file and added id to the 'table' tag, the localStorage worked perfectly but when I want to display, this happened:

```
id          Name        birthDay    Gender       Falcuty     Point
undefined   undefined   undefined   undefined   undefined   undefined
undefined   undefined   undefined   undefined   undefined   undefined
undefined   undefined   undefined   undefined   undefined   undefined
```

Please help me solve this problem!

Comment: Instead of iterating over the collection and adding each object to localstorage, why not stringify the collection and save that? Then you can just parse the whole thing back when you need to.

Comment: A Student is an object not an Array

Comment: I would consider about making that change after fixing this problem Andy

Comment: Jaromanda, thanks for reminding me

Answer (score 2):

The problem is mostly on the parts you're trying to loop over the keys of *Student*. Utilize `Object.keys` for achieving it instead:

```
function getStudents() {

  for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {

    var studentObjectSerialiseData = window.localStorage.getItem("student" + i)

    var temp = JSON.parse(studentObjectSerialiseData)
    var tr = document.createElement("tr")
    for (var j = 0; j < Object.keys(temp).length; j++) {
      var td = document.createElement("td")
      console.log(temp)
      td.innerText = temp[Object.keys(temp)[j]]
      tr.appendChild(td)
    }
    table.appendChild(tr)
  }
}
```

For a working example, see this snippet: https://jsbin.com/koqikiquzu/1/edit?html,js,output (Tried to embed through SO's own playground, but using `localStorage` is a bit tricky here).

Answer (score 1):

`temp` in `getStudents()` is an object so you need to loop over that too.

```
function getStudents() {
    for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
        var studentObjectSerialiseData = window.localStorage.getItem("student" + i)
        var temp = JSON.parse(studentObjectSerialiseData)
        var tr = document.createElement("tr")
        for (var j = 0; j < Student.length; j++) {
            for(var i in temp) {
                var td = document.createElement("td")
                td.innerText = temp[i]
                tr.appendChild(td)
            }
        }
        table.appendChild(tr)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the result by using for in loop inside j for loop and appends to tr tag if j and i are equal.

```
function getStudents() {    
    for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
      var studentObjectSerialiseData = window.localStorage.getItem("student" + i);
      var temp = JSON.parse(studentObjectSerialiseData);
      var tr = document.createElement("tr");
      for (var j = 0; j < Student.length; j++) {
        for (x in temp) {
          if (j == i) {
            var td = document.createElement("td");
            td.innerText = (temp)[x];
            tr.appendChild(td);
          }
        }
      }
      table.appendChild(tr)
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Access Student in a for in loop to get the keys.

```js
for(var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {

        var studentObjectSerialiseData = window.localStorage.getItem("student"+i)
        var temp = JSON.parse(studentObjectSerialiseData)
        console.log(temp);
        for(var j in Student) {    
            console.log(temp[j]) ;
        }

    }
```